# Stuck using .slice to remove a character in the value of an input field

Tags: javascript, slice, addeventlistener

I have some HTML:

`<input type="text" />`

and I'm trying to make it so that when the character limit hits 12 that javascript automatically deletes the next character from the input field. See code pen here: https://codepen.io/jadedeterville/pen/NWayzpM

Here is my JS:

```
inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", fixLength);

function fixLength() {
  const inputElValue = inputEl.value.length;
  if (inputElValue > 11) {
    inputEl.innerHTML.slice(12);
  }
}
```

I also tried `inputEl.slice(12);` and `inputElValue.slice(12);`but both of those tell me that .slice isn't a function.  I tried adding the toString() but that didn't work either.

Appreciate some advice. I've been looking at this for a long time.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
if (inputElValue > 11) {
  inputEl.value = inputEl.value.slice(0,12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes in your script:

1. With `inputEl.innerHTML.slice(12);` you're slicing anything from the start of the string up to index 12. So essentially you're clearing the whole string. If you want to keep a specific part of a string it's better to use `string.substr(startIndex, length)`
2. You don't assign the result of the slice operation to the `<input>` textbox e.g. `inputEl.innerHTML=inputEl.innerHTML.slice(12);`
3. you should use the `.value` property instead of `.innerHTML` as the latter will come up empty.

Putting it all together:

```js
let inputEl = document.getElementById("inp");

inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", fixLength);

function fixLength() {
  const inputElValue = inputEl.value.length;
  if (inputElValue > 11) {
    inputEl.value = inputEl.value.substr(0, 12);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```